# Don't quite understand logic of this nested loop - can't revise

Tags: python, loops, substring, repeat

I was looking for previously answered questions regarding finding repeated substrings in an array, and came across https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/79182/im-looking-for-an-algorithm-to-find-unknown-patterns-in-a-string. It does exactly what I want, except it analyzes a single string (and finds repetitions of single characters), whereas I'd like to analyze an array (with integers, some exceeding 9). I can't accomplish this with the code as is, because for example "10" would be understood as "1" and "0".

So instead of the example "ABACBABAABBCBABA", I'd want to analyze [A, B, A, C...]. More to the point, I'd eventually want to work with integers [1, 4, 3, 1, 4...]

I've tried modifying the code, however I don't think I fully understand the logic of the nested loop. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Can you explain what you *do* understand about this code?

Comment: For future reference, this is best asked in a comment, but I can see you don't yet have the privilege to comment. That's okay, but as soon as you can, use comments for these types of questions. I'll look into the loop.

Comment: Hi Scott - ok, I'm only a beginner so please bear with me. I kind of get what's inside the nested loop - I don't get what "i" does in the context of "sublen", but the rest is just comparison and checking (.count). I'm struggling with the logic of the outer loop. I don't understand the strategy of creating a range between the minimum required substring length and "inputString/minCount" (also, I don't understand what that quotient get you practically speaking)

Comment: Is there going to be a hard coded maximum value?

Comment: no, I'd actually like for the code to output what that max value is

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some work on the original problem, I still don't understand the reason for the outer loop, but I've managed to mimic the original reference script (for arrays instead of strings).

I wanted to post it in case someone else may find use for it. I'm sure it's not the most efficient way, but it seems to work. If anyone sees holes in it, by all means please advise:

```
def countSubs(total, sub):
    totalCount = 0

    for i in range(len(total) - len(sub) + 1):
        testCount = 0

        for j in range(len(sub)):
            if sub[j] == total[i + j]:
                testCount += 1

        if testCount == len(sub):
            totalCount += 1

    return totalCount

minLength = 3
minCount = 2

test = [1,2,1,3,2,-1,2,-1,2,4,2,4,2,5,2,5,2,5,6,7,-1,7,-1,8,7,6,-1,9,-1,9,8,7,10]
rectDict = {}

for sublen in range(minLength, int(len(test)/minCount)):

    for i in range(0, len(test) - sublen):
        sub = test[i:i + sublen]
        cnt = countSubs(test, sub)

        #not necessary to concatenate with commas, but for visual legibility
        subText = ''.join(str(e) + ',' for e in sub)

        if cnt >= minCount and subText not in recDict:
            recDict[subText[:-1]] = cnt

print(rectDict)
```